# How to repair path to updmap config files in MacTeX

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, mactex

I installed MacTeX 2012 on a freshly installed Mountain Lion. I now would have liked to install some special fonts (Trebuchet, Frutiger etc.). For that I made sure that all the font files are in

```
~/Library/texmf/
```

If I run

```
updmap --enable Map=jtr.map
```

(or even `updmap-sys`) I would receive this result:

```
updmap: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/anouak) to root's actual home (/var/root).
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /var/root/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /var/root/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/root/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/root/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/root/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "/var/root/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
    jtr.map (in /var/root/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)

    Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.
```

Indeed, I did run `mktexlsr` and a `kpsewhich jtr.map` results in:

```
/Users/anouak/Library/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/jtr.map
```

So it is there.

I also did a `--syncwithtrees` to disable the "non-existent" map entries, but unfortunately to no avail.

What is irritating to me is that `updmap` is trying to use config files in `/var/root/` or `/private/var/root/` respectively to which even I have rarely access and if then only with difficulties. Also, during my research in the web I found nobody citing this path.

Can anybody help me to get this weird problem solved? Because I need those additional fonts in order to cope with our corporate design.

Comment: You shouldn't worry that updmap uses various `cfg` files. Your problem is that the map-file is not found. Is `Users/anouak/Library/texmf/` really a texmf tree of your texlive2012? Do you have an older TeX-installation which could get in the way?

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike. Indeed, there is a texmf tree under /Users/anouak/Library/texmf/ and it used to work properly in former installations. That is even acknowleged by `kpsewhich` as it displays the proper path.
There cannot be any older TeX-Installation as the system is setup freshly new.

Comment: It's better to put the font related files in the local tree `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and run `sudo updmap-sys`, if you have Administrator privileges. In this way you'll not be concerned with font updates in the main tree.

Comment: Thank you egreg, that did the trick, which is quite disappointing as it was working properly in former distributions of TeXLive.
Thank you all for all your support.

Comment: Did you get the "resetting $HOME" message when you run it as normal user? That should not happen and would be a bug, please retry and confirm!

Comment: So I chcked the source code again. The resetting of the HOME directory should only happen when you call updmap via sudo. Well, but then this is what is expected ... root running updmap should not include *your*local* fonts in the system-wide config files.

If you want to have fonts local to one user, the user has to run updmap (without sudo!!).

Comment: Ping ping ping!? Can the OP confirm the problem, or anyone else?